# Transpose a PHP multidimensional array with predefined keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, transpose

I have a multidimensional array with 3 keys ("length", "width" and "height). Each key is associated with an array of values:

```
$data = [
    "length" => ["12", "44"],
    "width" => ["22", "45"],
    "height" => ["22", "34"]
];
```

How can I transpose the columns of each key into rows of 3 columns as follows:

```
$rows = [
    ["length" => "12", "width" => "22", "height" => "22"],
    ["length" => "44", "width" => "45", "height" => "34"]
];
```

Comment: What are the columns of your table in the database ?

Comment: What have you already tried to get those two new arrays (we are still not talking about isnserting but only about formatting data)? Do you know how to check length of input arrays and compare/confirm if those have the same element count? Have you used `for` loop with that element count and try to make new arrays from existing ones?

Comment: @YezanRafed one of the column name is lenght and width and height.

Comment: Lenght of input arrays is not fixed maybe have change in some times.@YezanRafed

Comment: I have lenght and width and height column. and i want save this data in two row of my data base because these arrays have two value. first value of all arrays in one row and second value of all arrays in Another row.
@YezanRafed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will do the job:

```
function transpose($data)
{
    $result = [];
    $keys = array_keys($data);
    for ($row = 0,  $rows = count(reset($data)); $row < $rows; $row++) {
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $result[$row][$key] = $data[$key][$row];
        }
    } 

    return $result;
}
```

Notice that the function is a general solution it doesn’t depend on the name of the keys nor on the number of entries of each key.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here's a one-liner that would work

```
$data = [
    "length" => ["12", "44"],
    "width" => ["22", "45"],
    "height" => ["22", "34"]
];

foreach ($data as $n => $v) foreach ($v as $vn => $vv) $new[$vn][$n]=$vv;
print_r($new);
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/OvSeQW8X6JBiDZ4i

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one to get the arrays like you said

```
   $height = array(12,44);
$width = array(20,50);
$length = array(30,50);
$new_array[0] = $height[0];
$new_array[1] = $width[0];
$new_array[2] = $length[0];
$new_array2 = $new_array[1];
print_r($new_array);
echo "<br>";
print_r($new_array2);
```

Comment: yes,you get first index in new arary but i want get second array too. I know should use loop but mabye i have 10 index in this array and i can get one element to store in loop