# Having trouble in converting array from array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have and array like this

```php
Array
(
    [ID] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

    [Ticket_ID] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => f
            [2] => g
            [3] => h
        )

    [Status] => Array
        (
            [0] => i
            [1] => j
            [2] => k
            [3] => l
        )
)
```

and i want it like this

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => a
            [Ticket_ID] => e
            [Status] => i
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => b
            [Ticket_ID] => f
            [Status] => j
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => c
            [Ticket_ID] => g
            [Status] => k
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => d
            [Ticket_ID] => h
            [Status] => l
        )
)
```

This is my code so far:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) { 
  if($k = 'ns0:Request_ID') { 
      foreach($v as $kk => $vv) { 
          array_push($sd ,$vv); 
      } 
  } 
  break; 
 }
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Just create a `for` loop based on one array's length and populate a new array using the index

Comment: is it that, every array i.e. ID, Ticket ID and and Status will have equal no. of items ??

Comment: Exactly, post your solution? Attempt?

Comment: foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
    if($k = 'ns0:Request_ID')
    {
        foreach($v as $kk => $vv)
        {
            array_push($sd ,$vv);
        }
    }
    break;
}

Comment: no there values may increase or decrease

Comment: i was going for an approach for pushing arrays one after other but i think it might not work

Comment: `$k = 'ns0:Request_ID'` is an assignment typo. Also what is `ns0:Request_ID` that isn't in example. Please post reproducible code and example.

Comment: I know the answer has been accepted, but here's an alternative (one-liner): https://stackoverflow.com/a/67877835/1772933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
//assuming initial data is in variable $data
$finalArray = [];

//assume that each "record" has an "ID" and as such the number of "ID" items
//will determine the number of records
if(isset($data['ID']) && is_array($data['ID'])){
    //determine number of records/items based on number of id elements
    $noOfItems = count($data['ID']);

    //foreach item check if an element exists in the respective
    //"Ticket_ID" and "Status" arrays based on the current index "$i"
    //Checks were included to ensure values were arrays and indexes were
    //present before use usinf `isset` and `is_array`. 
    // if a value did not exist for this index `null` was assigned.

    for($i=0;$i<$noOfItems;$i++){
         array_push($finalArray,[
             'ID'=>$data['ID'][$i],
             'Ticket_ID'=> ( 
                              isset($data['Ticket_ID']) &&  
                              is_array($data['Ticket_ID']) &&
                              isset($data['Ticket_ID'][$i])
                           ) ? $data['Ticket_ID'][$i] : null,
             'Status'=> ( 
                              isset($data['Status']) &&  
                              is_array($data['Status']) &&
                              isset($data['Status'][$i])
                           ) ? $data['Status'][$i] : null
         ]);
    }
}
//final results are in $finalArray
```

Comment: You could shorten your array building to things like `'Ticket_ID'=> $data['Ticket_ID'][$i] ?? null`

Comment: its solved thanks for the solution and we can add multiple values here too Great..